# Can I use azure to deploy custom load balancing algorithm?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, iaas

Can I use azure to deploy an algorithm for load balancing that I read in one of the research papers? If yes how should i approach the problem and if no then please suggest some alternatives.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azure provides in-built public and private load balancing and DNS-based routing capabilities (Traffic Manager).

If you want to run your own load balancing infrastructure you can do that but you'd have to run it on Azure Virtual Machines and utilise Virtual Networking to allow you to connect multiple load balanced instances to your load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

For custom load balancing beyond what is available in Traffic Manager, then you'll need to deploy an F5 app and route traffic trough that app to your website.